# Class not found exception with google maps api v2 and eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I want to write a simple map program. I am using eclipse. I get the following exceptions:

```
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): Process: com.example.mapapp, PID: 7341
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start          activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapapp/com.example.mapapp.MapAppHome}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at com.example.mapapp.MapAppHome.onCreate(MapAppHome.java:13)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     ... 11 more
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an   empty constructor that is public
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     ... 21 more
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mapapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-  lib/com.example.mapapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
05-06 10:25:33.474: E/AndroidRuntime(7341):     ... 24 more
```

Here is my android manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapapp.MapAppHome"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my_code"/>
</application>
```

here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my activity code:

```
package com.example.mapapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MapAppHome extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_app_home);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_app_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

google play services lib is in eclipse's workspace and referenced (to mapapp properties) and it does not matter (same errors) if it is within workspace folder or not.
I have a valid api key which I used in the same project at android studio this time and it worked perfectly. 
The project build api is set to Google api 4.4.2 and in order and export tab in java build path in project properties, all options are checked (Google Api, android private libraries and android dependecies).
As I said before the same code with the necessary (grandle) changes works perfectly. All my sdk files are up to date.

What I am missing?

Comment: extend fragmentActivity

Comment: same result and error.